# Color background within price range of only latest 5 candle ( highest and lowest price level)

Tags: plot, pine-script, highest

I want to color the background of price range within the latest 5 candle.
Get the highest price and lowest price among them and color the background.
Other previous candle ( candle 6 and previous ) I just want to ignore.

I'm newbie and still learning.

I try using :

```
highest(5)
lowest(5)
```

and

```
highest(high, 5)
lowest(low, 5)
```

But it didn't work for me.

Here's the closet example form Kodify web. But need to enter the price range manually.

```
//@version=4
study(title="Colour background in price range", overlay=true)

// STEP 1:
// Configure price range with inputs


rangeUp = input(title="Price Range Upper Bound", type=input.float, defval=1, minval=0)
rangeDown = input(title="Price Range Lower Bound", type=input.float, defval=0.95, minval=0)

fullBarInRange = input(title="Full Bar In Range?", type=input.bool, defval=false)

// STEP 2:
// Check if bar falls in range, based on input
insideRange = if fullBarInRange
    high < rangeUp and low > rangeDown
else
    high > rangeDown and low < rangeUp

// STEP 3:
// Plot range's upper and lower bound
ubPlot = plot(series=insideRange ? rangeUp : na, style=plot.style_linebr, transp=100, title="Upper Bound")
lbPlot = plot(series=insideRange ? rangeDown : na, style=plot.style_linebr, transp=100, title="Lower Bound")

// STEP 4:
// Fill the background for bars inside the price range
fill(plot1=ubPlot, plot2=lbPlot, color=#FF8C00, transp=75)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Version 1

This will fill between the highest/lowest of the last 5 bars:

```
//@version=4
study("Hi/Lo Range", "", true)
p = input(5)
hi = highest(p)
lo = lowest(p)
p_hi = plot(hi, "Hi")
p_lo = plot(lo, "Lo")
fill(p_hi, p_lo)
```

[image]

#### Version 2

```
//@version=4
study("Hi/Lo Range", "", true)
p = input(5)
hi = highest(p)
lo = lowest(p)
p_hi = plot(hi, "Hi", show_last = 5)
p_lo = plot(lo, "Lo", show_last = 5)
fill(p_hi, p_lo, show_last = 5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks PineCoders-LucF.. But is there any way i can just color the last 5 candle and ignore the rest previous candle ( candle 6 and previous )

Comment: Yes. See version 2 of the answer.

Comment: Dear Coders,
I would like to improve the script and create it like this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8swCa.png

1 .The box will display 30 boxes backward, start from latest candle (Monday, trading day)
2. The boxes shouldn't move when new candle appear/born because I need to see the progress/trend.

Thanks and hope to get feedback and idea :)

Comment: Try the "Multi-Time Period Charts" built-in.